# Inner product of function

Tags: calculus, vectors

I know that the following question can be solved with the traditional slope method, but I was thinking of using inner product here, which I learned recently.

> Question: If $ x + y = \lambda$ is normal to $y^2 = 12x$ then value of
>   $\lambda$ is?

Here is my approach to the problem.
$$ \langle y_1(x) | y_2(x) \rangle = \int y_1(x)y_2(x) dx = 0 $$
$$ y_1(x)y_2(x) = 0 $$
$$ (\lambda - x)\sqrt{x} = 0 $$
Two values are coming from the above equation $x = \lambda, 0$. I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: I guess that your whole approach is wrong...

Comment: Maybe.  Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: You should try to understand if the "normality" condition is actually meant in the $L^2$ sense. I'd rather say that here the problem is concerned with two normal *curves* in the sense of differential geometry: the tangent lines at the intersection point are perpendicular.

Comment: Could you explain "normality" in $L^2$.

Comment: Simply $\int fg =0$.

Comment: I was searching for a point where this condition will satisfy (seeking the value of $\lambda$). I think in this process I'm reducing the solution space to zero, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

In real case the inner product is defining in an interval such as $[0,1]$ or $[-\pi,\pi]$ and et. You should define inner product exactly equate it zero then you will get an equation that $\lambda $ will be found.